# Handling non UTF-8 data in JSON file

Tags: php, json, utf-8

I am obtaining a JSON file from a location and passing the contents to my frontend.  To do this, I have something like the following

```
return response()->json(json_decode(file_get_contents('some/path', true)));
```

Sometimes however, I have noticed that this fails due to malformed utf-8 characters.  I have looked at the JSON file, and noticed that sometimes some things like £ signs are being represented as a weird symbol e.g.

```
{
  "ID": "123",
  "Date": "08/06/2012",
  "Amount": "�120.59"
}
```

What would be the best way to handle a situation like this?  At the moment, I am trying something like the following

```
$data = file_get_contents('some/path', true);
$encoding = mb_detect_encoding($data, mb_detect_order(), true);
if($encoding !== "UTF-8") {
    return response()->json(json_decode(utf8_decode($data)));
}
return response()->json(json_decode($data));
```

This seems to work but not sure if it is the best way?  The reason I am checking if it is UTF-8 is because if I try to use `utf8_decode` on something that is already UTF-8, it fails.

Would this be the best approach to handling strange characters within the JSON file?

Thanks

Comment: What's the encoding used when it is not UTF8? Because [utf8_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) only encodes ISO-8859-1. [mb_convert_encoding()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) can do more.

Comment: To be honest I have no idea.  When there are no funny characters it seems to be UTF-8.  When there are funny characters, detect_encoding returns false

Comment: `mb_detect_encoding()` probably returns false because the bit of `$data` is too small to dectect the encoding, but it knows it can't be UTF-8. I can't judge your situation, but it would make sense to find out what the encoding really is. I suspect the bits that seem to be UTF-8, are in the same encoding but missing non-UTF-8 characters. So if you would know the true encoding you can deal with all the data correctly.

Comment: If it is not some sensitive information, can you post here sample JSON file? I'm talking about posting full file, not copypasting it -- that would remove most of the interesting info like BOM (UTF header) etc.

Answer (score 1):

JSON is UTF-8 by definition - you should be using UTF-8 consequently: all your PHP scripts should be in UTF-8, any Database table and of course the communication channel between your scripts and the database, and finally the output.

If you have achieved this, your problem will vanish automatically... no more conversions required.

Comment: The only issue is I do not control the JSON file, I just grab it from another server.  I am looking at json_decode, would this be an option? `return response()->json(json_decode($data, true, 512, JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE));`

Comment: If you receive an JSON with invalid symbols, the creator has fucked this up... in this case you might have little chances of restoring the original (depending on how it was converted before). If you can, ask the creator to check this on his end...